# Separable Algebra, Equivalence of Definitions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, tensor-products

[This wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra) page gives two equivalent definitions for separable algebras.

> (1) An associative $K$-algebra $A$ is said to be separable if for every field
>   extension $L/K$ the
>   algebra $ A\otimes_K L$ is semisimple.

and

> (2) An algebra $A$ is separable if and only if it is projective when
>   considered as a left module of $A\otimes_K A^{op}$in the usual way.

How would I go about showing that these two definitions are equivalent?

EDIT (An Attempt):

(2)$\implies (1)$
Since $A$ is projective a short exact sequence
$$
M\to N\to A\to 0
$$ splits, i.e. $N\cong M\oplus A$.  We can think of $L/K$ as a module over the field $K$ (e.g $L=\mathbb{C}$ and $K=\mathbb{R}$).  Now, the tensor product is right exact so that 
$$
M\otimes L \to M\otimes L\oplus A\otimes L\to A\otimes L\to 0
$$ is also exact.  Hence, $A\otimes L$ is a summand of a free module therefore semisimple apriori.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/separable-algebras/). I don't know a way to prove this that doesn't involve just classifying the separable algebras over a field.